# confused with karma for testing an angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I've been planning to study how to test my AngularJS app for more than 6 months now. Unfortunately, since I'm the only frontend developer, I've been so swamped with feature request. I'm unable to put time to doing unit-testing. However, I told the team during this Agile Sprint, I should really add codes for unit-testing. I was able to request 3 days dedicated for learning unit-testing.

I actually have already done research before. I found Karma. I remember installing it. Today, I installed it again. Now I've very confused. When I executed unix find, this is what I got.

```
19:29 ~/repos/baam/baam-ui $ find ~/.npm -name 'karma*'

/Users/admin/.npm/chai/1.9.1/package/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/chai/1.9.1/package/karma.sauce.js
/Users/admin/.npm/deep-eql/0.1.3/package/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/bin/karma
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/integration-tests/coffee/karma.conf.coffee
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/integration-tests/coverage-coffee/karma.conf.coffee
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/integration-tests/coverage-jasmine/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/integration-tests/coverage-mocha-requirejs/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/integration-tests/coverage-qunit/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/integration-tests/dojo/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/integration-tests/html2js/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/integration-tests/jasmine/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/integration-tests/jasmine_2/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/integration-tests/junit/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/integration-tests/live-script/karma.conf.ls
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/integration-tests/mocha/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/integration-tests/qunit/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/integration-tests/requirejs/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/integration-tests/saucelabs/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/karma-0.12.11.tgz
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/karma-completion.sh
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/lib/middleware/karma.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.12/package/static/karma.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/bin/karma
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/integration-tests/coffee/karma.conf.coffee
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/integration-tests/coverage-coffee/karma.conf.coffee
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/integration-tests/coverage-jasmine/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/integration-tests/coverage-mocha-requirejs/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/integration-tests/coverage-qunit/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/integration-tests/dojo/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/integration-tests/html2js/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/integration-tests/jasmine/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/integration-tests/jasmine_2/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/integration-tests/junit/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/integration-tests/live-script/karma.conf.ls
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/integration-tests/mocha/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/integration-tests/qunit/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/integration-tests/requirejs/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/integration-tests/saucelabs/karma.conf.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/karma-0.12.13.tgz
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/karma-completion.sh
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/lib/middleware/karma.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/static/karma.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.16/package/bin/karma
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.16/package/karma-completion.sh
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.16/package/lib/middleware/karma.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.16/package/static/karma.js
/Users/admin/.npm/karma-chai
/Users/admin/.npm/karma-chrome-launcher
/Users/admin/.npm/karma-coverage
/Users/admin/.npm/karma-firefox-launcher
/Users/admin/.npm/karma-jasmine
/Users/admin/.npm/karma-mocha
/Users/admin/.npm/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor
/Users/admin/.npm/karma-ng-scenario
/Users/admin/.npm/karma-phantomjs-launcher
/Users/admin/.npm/karma-requirejs
/Users/admin/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/karma
/Users/admin/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/karma-chai
/Users/admin/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/karma-chrome-launcher
/Users/admin/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/karma-coverage
/Users/admin/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/karma-jasmine
/Users/admin/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/karma-mocha
/Users/admin/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor
/Users/admin/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/karma-ng-scenario
/Users/admin/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/karma-phantomjs-launcher
```

Looks like I've got multiple versions now. I manually executed the karma binaries, and I got this output.

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'optimist'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/.npm/karma/0.12.14/package/lib/cli.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I couldn't recall which tutorials I've followed before so I'm not sure which commands I've executed. I also saw karma.conf.js on my Angular project. I'm not sure why I have one there. File is dated July 12, 2014.

I'm not sure how to restart my karma installation without affecting my project. I would like to have a clean and working karma. I also want to learn how to test my application.

Oh, I remember reading protractor too but I don't know if I installed it. I would like to use the best unit-testing for angular. So far, I read it's karma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at there with the different version is the npm cache.  npm will cache all of the packages and all of the version it downloads so it will be faster to install them when they are needed again.

What you need to do is install karma as a dev dependency (`npm install karma --save-dev`) as well as all of the karma 'plugins' (things that start with `karma-`) that you want to use in the project you want to use them with.

Karma is just a test runner, you end up writing your tests in something like [mocha](http://mochajs.org/) or [jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/).  Karma basically starts a server, launches some browsers (or you can manually connect) and runs your test files.  It then gets the results and outputs them to the 'reporter' of your choosing (like the console/terminal).

There are also things like [chai](http://chaijs.com/) and [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) that work well with mocha to allow for easier testing.  There are usually karma plugins version for those, and even a [karma-chai-sinon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-chai-sinon)

Karma uses a [config file](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html) (typically named karma.conf.js) to tell it what reporters to use, what test frameworks to use, what browsers to automatically test in, what files will be accessible through the server it runs, and other things.

You can throw a task runner (like [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) with [gulp-karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/gulp-karma)) on top so you can build your project and then test it all in one command.

You will also want to get [ngMocks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock) to write test for angular.

Protractor is the end-to-end tester made by the angular team to be used with angular.

Comment: Thank you I got it working. http://i.imgur.com/pEK9T7Z.png Now, how do I write a test case?

Comment: I'm trying this one right now, https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/testing-angular-with-karma

Comment: I find it best to learn by examples.  Pick your favorite angular project and look at it's test.  Or check out something like the tests for https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io

Comment: I think I get it now after seeing that link you gave. Looks like the spec.js should contain our test codes. These spec js files should also be added in karma.conj.js. Since karma knows that it's a test code, I will execute it. Correct?

Comment: I got it working TheSharpieOne. Check this out - https://gist.github.com/c0debreaker/a2ee99a168d507f42b9d However, all I see is that it passed the 18 tests. Is it possible to see those 18 test being executed in browser? I remember last year, my officemate used jasmine on our BackboneJS application, I saw the test cases in the browser.

Comment: There is not really anything to see, these are just unit tests.  You only really care about pass/fail.  If it passes, you see what you saw.  If it fails, you usually get a stack trace to figure out what happened.  You can use a [different reporter](https://www.google.com/search?q=karma+report&oq=karma+report&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.3295j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=karma+reporter) to output the information differently, even in HTML to view in the browser.